# proguard + crashlytics crash

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, android-proguard, twitter-fabric

I have integrated Crashlytics in my project, Now when I enable proguard, App Crashes. Have tried to exclude all the classes from crashlytics with no success

File proguard-rules.pro file has the following

```
-keep class io.fabric.sdk.android.** { *; }
-keep interface io.fabric.sdk.android.** { *; }
-keep class com.digits.sdk.android.core.** { *; }
-keep interface com.digits.sdk.android.core.** { *; }
-keep class com.twitter.sdk.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.twitter.sdk.android.** { *; }

-keep class io.fabric.** { *; }
-keep interface io.fabric.** { *; }
-keep class com.digits.** { *; }
-keep interface com.digits.** { *; }
-keep class com.twitter.** { *; }
-keep interface com.twitter.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep interface com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

I am getting an error as

```
com.example.app E/Answers: Failed to submit events task
    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@1d060ef0 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@31c1ac69[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 9]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:298)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:593)
        at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.executeAsync(Unknown Source)
        at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEvent(Unknown Source)
```

I have also looked at crashlytics document and tried every possible combinations.
can someone please guide me on this

Comment: Mike from Fabric here - just curious, why do you think this is Proguard related? The error appears to be on submission of an event, not on build or compile when the Proguard settings would take effect. 

What type of event are you trying to submit when this error happens? Also, can you share your Fabric init code?

Comment: Yes, this issue was not from Fabric, This got solved after I excluded other classes not related to fabric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html) -

> First of all, Fabric uses annotations internally, so add the following
>   line to your configuration file:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

> Next, in order to provide the most meaningful crash reports, add the
>   following line to your configuration file:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

> If you are using custom exceptions, add this line so that custom
>   exception types are skipped during obfuscation:

```
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

Comment: Thanks, But we have tried all these things, Not working for us :(